# C# MVC Adding a string to an HTML page using stream reader / writer in web page editor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my project i have an editor that uses drag and drop. This part cannot use drag and drop because the html style is set to 'display: none'. I have what i need to create this but i am in need of some guidance on how to get what i have and add it to the page.

I have a dropdown that allows me to select from a database, what records i want. Then it displays those records in the below code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectTags(TagsModel model)
    {
        List<Tags> selectedTags = new List<Tags>();
        foreach (var t in model.Tags.Where(x => x.IsChecked))
        selectedTags.Add(t);

        return Content(String.Join("<br>", selectedTags.Select(x => "&lsaquo;div id=&quot;hmi-tag-defs&quot;&nbsp;" + "id=&quot;" + x.TagsId + "&quot; &nbsp;" + "data-hmi-address= &quot;" + x.DataHmiAddress + "&quot; &nbsp;" + "data-hmi-data-type=&quot;" + x.DataHmiDataType + "&quot; &nbsp;" + "data-hmi-round-places=&quot;" + x.DataHmiRoundPlaces + "&quot; &nbsp;" + "data-hmi-update-level=&quot;" + x.DataHmiUpdateLevel + "&quot; &nbsp;" + "data-hmi-update-in=&quot;" + x.DataHmiUpdateIn + "&quot;" + "style=&quot;display: none;&quot; &rsaquo;&lsaquo;&frasl;div&rsaquo;")));
    }
```

This appears to be pretty ugly, I had to use markup to get it to present right. If there is a cleaner way to present this I am open to it. This brings back the below on selected items.

```
‹div id="hmi-tag-defs" id="0"  data-hmi-address= "F1234"  data-hmi-data-type="float"  data-hmi-round-places="5"  data-hmi-update-level="100"  data-hmi-update-in="8"style="display: none;" ›‹⁄div›
‹div id="hmi-tag-defs" id="0"  data-hmi-address= "F1235"  data-hmi-data-type="float"  data-hmi-round-places="2"  data-hmi-update-level="1"  data-hmi-update-in="100"style="display: none;" ›‹⁄div›
```

Instead of displaying this on the page i would like it to read this and insert it on the current html page that is being developed. This project is very Javascript heavy, if that route is the easiest then we can use that as well. 
In the end there needs to be other HTML added to this before it is placed on the page. The End result would look like this.

```
<div id="hmi-user-tag-defs" style="display: none;">
    <div class="hmi-tag-def" id="hmi-tag.F1234" data-hmi-address="F1234" data-hmi-data-type="float" data-hmi-value="2.345" data-hmi-round-places="5" data-hmi-update-level="100" data-hmi-update-in="8" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="hmi-tag-def" id="hmi-tag.MinGood" data-hmi-address="F0001" data-hmi-data-type="float" data-hmi-value="6" data-hmi-round-places="5" data-hmi-update-level="100" data-hmi-update-in="2" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

The beginning opening tags and end tags. Which i am assuming i can just add with 'var' or 'string' like this

```
var st = "<div id='hmi-user-tag-defs' style='display: none;'>";
var et = "</div>";
var content = "";
var final = st + content + et;
```

Then read 'final' and then write it to the HTML page. This is an area that i am not really familiar with if someone has an idea of how to achieve this or where i can find some examples etc., I would appreciate it. Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: An Important note i forgot to add. This page that gets created will be a HTML page running on a browser locally. No server side code can be used once this is on the page.

Comment: What's the point of the V in MVC if you're going to render pieces of Html in your action method and return them to the client? *"If there is a cleaner way to present this I am open to it"* Try using a partial view.

Comment: @derloopkat So that this is more clear, The MVC project itself is the developement area to create HTML Pages. The user will not have access to the MVC Project, only the developer. The above portion is something that is created in the MVC project but saved to the HTML page. So i need a way to put that code into the developement page so the user has it.